# Add hours and minutes from string into datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

```
string date = "17:25";
if(date.Lenght == 5){
    myobj.StartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    // add only hh and minutes and preserve day and year
}
else if(date.Lenght > 5){
    myobj.StartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

myobj.StartTime is obviously of `DateTime` datatype.

I know I could break this string on `:` and use first part as hours and then convert that to double and then use AddHours, and I should repeat that for minutes also but I'm wonder is there convenient way to do this?

Comment: You might also want to spell `Length` correctly :-).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `TimeSpan.ParseExact`:

```
myobj.StartTime = myobj.StartTime.Add(TimeSpan.ParseExact(date, "hh\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

In `hh\\:mm` `hh` are hours (you cannot use `HH` here, not supported by this concrete method), `mm` are minutes, and `\\:` is escaped `:` character. One slash is to escape slash itself in C# literal string (otherwise you can do this: `@"hh\:mm"`), and you need to escape `:` with slash in format string, because otherwise `TimeSpan.ParseExact` will treat it as custom format specifier (like `h`), but there is no such format specifier and it will throw invalid format exception.

Note that if you also allow single-digit hours and minutes (like this: "1:2" or "1:25") - then you have to use another format:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(date, @"h\:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This format will handle *both* single-digit and two-digit hours and minutes.

Also note that if you have more than 24 hours in your string (like "25:11") - this method will not work and you will have to fallback to split (as far as I know).

Comment: can you please describe in short this hh\\:mm

Comment: Updated answer with that explanation.